# If cell is blank, return specific text; if cell is not blank return the value in that cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I am creating a data results tab that pulls data from tabs where data is collected/recorded. In the data results tab, if the cell is blank (nothing was selected from the drop-down), I want it to populate with "No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned." If it is populated, I want it to return the value that it is populated with.

All the formulas I have found allow you to return the text when the cell is blank, or certain values based on the values of the cell, but not the exact value of the source cell. For example:

`=IF(RA!P8<>"","No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned")` -- only works when the cell is blank

`=IF(ISBLANK(RA!P8),"No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned", IF(RA!P8=0,"zero","other"))`, doesn't work because I need it to populate the actual value in the cell.

Theoretically, this is what I'm looking for:

```
=IF(AND(IF(RA!P8<>"","No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned"),IF(RA!P8=any other value,J10=RA!P8)))
```

Comment: Maybe in cell `J10` you are looking to put the following `=IF(RA!P8="","No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned",RA!P8)`

Comment: Ahh!! Yes! So I feel like I should have tried this among my many attempts but maybe I didn't. This should have been obvious. :) Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your final formula doesn't makes any sense, since  you are testing `RA!P8<>" ", Value,RA!P8 = Any value`, in fact both contradicts each other. Test for `Blank` & `ANY VALUE`.  should liek this `=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A250),"No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned",IF(Sheet1!A250 =10,Sheet1!A250))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Rogers provided a solution that worked perfectly:

> Maybe in cell J10 you are looking to put the following:
>   `=IF(RA!P8="","No Dominant Root Cause was Assigned",RA!P8)`

This formula worked perfectly and solved my problem!

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In another day, you will be able to accept your own answer (click the checkmark next to it).  That will indicate that the problem has been solved.